# How do I add a user to the wheel group in Redhat even if the user does not exist?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

In SUSE the command `groupmod -A "username" wheel` will add any user, even if they don't exist, to the wheel group.

In Redhat the `-A` argument does not exist. and other tools such as `groupmems` will not add the user if they don't already exist.

How can I add a non-existant user to the wheel group with Redhat CLI native tools?

- im using quest tools and this is a domain user so the user is not locally configured.
- i know that there are other ways for getting the permissions configured but i want to do this by adding it to the wheel.

Comment: Why don't you just create the user first?

Comment: im using quest tools and this is a domain user so the user is not locally configured.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that relevant information.

Comment: "Domain user" shouldn't matter any... If the user can be resolved _at all_ (whether by LDAP, NIS, or AD) it can be added to groups.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
usermod -aG wheel 'username'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just define the user in the sudoers file - should be the same effect as adding a user to the wheel group.

So as root/sudo, just run the following:

```
echo 'username ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: i know that there are other ways for getting the permissions configured but i want to do this by adding it to the wheel.